# how to use where with orderby in flutter

Tags: flutter

how to use where with orderBy in flutter.

any one can tell me how these indexes are working and how to properly create them.

```
Query query = Firestore.instance
        .collection('clients')
        .where('sequenceStatus', isEqualTo: sequenceName)
        .orderBy('created', descending: true)
        .limit(20);
```

W/Firestore(19854): (19.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(clients where sequenceStatus == quotes order by -created, -**name**) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/rigatoinfissitest/database/firestore/indexes?create_composite=ClFwcm9qZWN0cy9yaWdhdG9pbmZpc3NpdGVzdC9kYXRhYmFzZXMvKGRlZmF1bHQpL2NvbGxlY3Rpb25Hcm91cHMvY2xpZW50cy9pbmRleGVzL18QARoSCg5zZXF1ZW5jZVN0YXR1cxABGgsKB2NyZWF0ZWQQAhoMCghfX25hbWVfXxAC, cause=null}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow below 5 steps or start from 3rd step after redirecting on above link you have posted in the question.

1. Go to your firebase console database
2. Select Indexes from there. Click on Add index.
3. Enter `clients` (collection name) in Collection ID field.
4. Add `sequenceStatus` (where clause field) in 1st field and leave Ascending as it is.
5. Add `created` (orderby field) 2nd field and leave Ascending as it is.
6. Click Create index.

Now, run your query. It will work just fine.

Cheers!

Comment: the same way as I mentioned in sequence?

Comment: it's working i'm sorry i want created as in descending order. it's working fine thanks for helping me.

Comment: No issues. I am glad it helps you.

Comment: Query q1 = _firestore .collection('clients') 
.where('isStar', isEqualTo: false) .where('isStar', isEqualTo: null) .orderBy('created', descending: true) .limit(perPage); is this query two fields indexes or three because firebase can't access one field for multiple indexes in one index.

Comment: you are checking isStar == false and null at the same time? how can this be correct?

Comment: it's like logical OR condition and in my firebase by default there's null value in this field.

Comment: so you have put OR, not try to do like this.

Comment: hello @Muhammad Noman can i check where condition on array field in firebse. like ``` .where('array_name', condition == null)

Comment: i want to filter out those data from firebase an array name as poserName which has not null value using where condition.

Comment: unfortunately, you cannot do that. You have to get that poserName array in data and then check the length of that array.

Comment: Yes, you're right i also finally came to this solution check the length of the array.

Comment: hello @Muhammad Noman can i perform where clause on specific document in cloud firestore.

Comment: @ParthBhanderi yes you can, it will return you all the related documents from that collection having that where condition applies

Comment: These steps were very helpful as I didn't understand how to implement indexing with firestore.

Comment: @Yushin I am glad :)