# How to use orderby with where(isNotEqualTo) in flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("crush")
          .where("user", isNotEqualTo: user.email)
          .orderBy("date", descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
```

I have already add date and user in index (Firebase)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and I found the solution.

It's because of some firebase limitation:

"If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field"
source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations

So in your context, you'll have to do the following:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("crush")
          .where("user", isNotEqualTo: user.email)
          .orderBy("user", descending: true)
          .orderBy("date", descending: true)
          .snapshots()
```

I believe you also need to create an index for those fields, you can refer to this question: [how to use where with orderby in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372921/how-to-use-where-with-orderby-in-flutter)

I hope it solves the problem for you as it did for me!

Comment: at the end I put on the page that the text coming from the same user.email were put in (widget) )Visible -> False