# Use where('x', arrayContainsAny: x) with orderBy Date

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Jobs')
          .where('types', arrayContainsAny: selectedRooms)
          .orderBy('types', descending: true)
          .orderBy('date', descending: true)
          .limit(30)
          .get();
```

I've already checked

1. [How to use orderby with where(isNotEqualTo) in flutter Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67514859/how-to-use-orderby-with-whereisnotequalto-in-flutter-firestore)
2. [How to use orderby with where(isNotEqualTo) in flutter Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67514859/how-to-use-orderby-with-whereisnotequalto-in-flutter-firestore) 
   but with no luck
   I've already created an index for

> 1. types: asc
> 2. date: asc

Update:

```
JobID: UID 
publisherName: String
Types: Array<String>
date: Timestamp
title: String
address: String
```

Any Help will be appreciated! Happy Coding

Comment: Are you getting an error or are you perhaps not getting the results you want returned? Do you have a model of the data that you are querying available?

Comment: No error is shown and no data is returning from the query.  I'll update my question with the model as soon as I get home.

Comment: Can you update your question with model?

Comment: @RoopaM Sorry for so late response. I've found the solution. There's another type specifically for array on firebase when you create the Index But you can see it only if you use the Firebase QueryBuilder. Thanks for the help Anyway

Comment: Happy to hear that your issue is resolved. Can you share your solution so that it will help others too.

Comment: Just posted my answer! Hopefully it will help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several tries without success I've managed to solved this by using the

`Firebase QueryBuilder` 
Basically what this does it shows a new type to use in the index which is `Array` Otherwise not selectable if you create the index by yourself. So the new Generated Index is

> 1. types: Array
> 2. date: asc

While keeping the same query as mentioned on the question this solved my problem. 
Thanks to everybody!